# How to get correct return value for suspend function when using GlobalScope.launch?

Tags: kotlin

I have a suspend function

```
private suspend fun getResponse(record: String): HashMap<String, String> {}
```

When I call it in my main function I'm doing this, but the type of response is Job, not HashMap, how can I get the correct return type?

```
override fun handleRequest(event: SQSEvent?, context: Context?): Void? {
        event?.records?.forEach {
            try {

                val response: Job = GlobalScope.launch {

                    getResponse(it.body)
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                logger.error("error message")
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in `handleRequest`? Do you want to call all `getResponse` concurrently?

Comment: @Joffrey it's an aws lambda function, when it got invoke I want to call getResponse to do something.

Comment: I think the question was: why do you need to use `launch()`? Do you need to run several `getResponse()` in parallel? Do you need to avoid blocking some thread? Answer will be a little different in both cases.

Comment: @WCY I'm sorry but you're being very vague. broot is correct, I'm asking about why you're using `launch`, basically trying to figure out what you're trying to do with it in order to give you proper help. For instance, do you care about all `getResponse` finishing before doing something else? Or do you just want to run something after `getResponse` for each element?

Comment: @broot, I don't need to run several getResponse in parallel, and no concern about blocking others, just try to get the correct result from getResponse(). I tried launch() here, but if it's incorrect, I will change to the correct one

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, just wanna do something after getResponse

Comment: But if you don't need a concurrent processing and/or blocking is no concern then why do you need `launch()`/`async()` at all?

Comment: @broot I think OP's just trying to call a `suspend` function from a non-suspending context

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes sense :-)

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answers in the comments, it looks like you're not looking for concurrency here. The best course of action would then be to just make `getRequest()` a regular function instead of a `suspend` one.

Assuming you can't change this, you need to call a `suspend` function from a regular one. To do so, you have several options depending on your use case:

1. block the current thread while you do your async stuff
2. make `handleRequest` a `suspend` function
3. make `handleRequest` take a `CoroutineScope` to start coroutines with some lifecycle controlled externally, but that means `handleRequest` will return immediately and the caller has to deal with the running coroutines (please don't use `GlobalScope` for this, it's a [delicate API](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/))

Option 2 and 3 are provided for completeness, but most likely in your context these won't work for you. So you have to block the current thread while `handleRequest` is running, and you can do that using `runBlocking`:

```kotlin
override fun handleRequest(event: SQSEvent?, context: Context?): Void? {
    runBlocking { 
        // do your stuff
    }
    return null
}
```

Now what to do inside `runBlocking` depends on what you want to achieve.

- if you want to process elements sequentially, simply call `getResponse` directly inside the loop:

```kotlin
override fun handleRequest(event: SQSEvent?, context: Context?): Void? {
    runBlocking {
        event?.records?.forEach {
            try {
                val response = getResponse(it.body)

                // do something with the response

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                logger.error("error message")
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

- If you want to process elements concurrently, but independently, you can use `launch` and put both `getResponse()` and the code using the response inside the `launch`:

```kotlin
override fun handleRequest(event: SQSEvent?, context: Context?): Void? {
    runBlocking {
        event?.records?.forEach {
            launch { // coroutine scope provided by runBlocking
                try {
                    val response = getResponse(it.body)

                    // do something with the response

                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    logger.error("error message")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

- If you want to get the responses concurrently, but process all responses only when they're all done, you can use `map` + `async`:

```kotlin
override fun handleRequest(event: SQSEvent?, context: Context?): Void? {
    runBlocking {
        val responses = event?.records?.mapNotNull {
            async { // coroutine scope provided by runBlocking
                try {
                    getResponse(it.body)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    logger.error("error message")
                    null // if you want to still handle other responses
                    // you could also throw an exception otherwise
                }
            }
        }.map { it.await() }

        // do something with all responses
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Taking a step back, it seems `getResponse` should just be redefined as a non-suspend function. The API probably has synchronous overloads for whatever methods they're calling.

Comment: @Tenfour04 tes, I'm assuming the OP didn't have a choice here, but that might be a wrong assumption to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GlobalScope.async()` instead of `launch()` - it returns `Deferred`, which is a future/promise object. You can then call `await()` on it to get a result of `getResponse()`.

Just make sure not to do something like: `async().await()` - it wouldn't make any sense, because it would still run synchronously. If you need to run `getResponse()` on all `event.records` in parallel, then you can first go in loop and collect all deffered objects and then await on all of them.